# Can I create group & private chat app in socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I want to create a chat application which will includes the following functionalities.

1) Group Chat.
2) Private Chat.
3) Images can be share and show in realtime in Group and Private chat
4) Give Option of Who is typing.

I want to create above application in `react.js`, `node.js` & `socket.io`.

**Can I?**

Comment: https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/build-a-simple-chat-app-with-node-js-and-socket-io-ea716c093088

Comment: Yes you can do all of that, but it would require a lot of logic and planning. Socketio has "namespaces" and "rooms". Also, it allows you to send a "buffer", which means you could send an image(and you would have to process it later in the browser as an image)

Comment: I am trying to make something similar very long time with same tools as you.and still no success,i m afraid than react isnt the happiest solution for our project.